# Prerequisites for the study of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm an undergrad student having knowledge in Abstract Algebra, Linear Algebra and some of the Commutative Algebra. I have a keen interest in Algebraic Geometry as a subject and I want to pursue my future research in it. But, I find it hard to know about the prerequisites for the subject. I randomly search for this topic on internet but that doesn't satisfy me as all I want is to find the chronological order to understand and go deep down into the subject with the knowledge I have right now.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is enough to start - at least with varieties. For scheme theory, you may still wanna learn some category theory (and things like topology and geometry on the way).

Comment: If you realize that it becomes tough while reading (and it will, algebraic geometry is no joke!), then simply go back to the prerequisites and study those. On the other hand, I must warn you not to leave the "foundations" too quickly. Many young students (such as myself) are too eager to start with the "fancier theory" too early and realize quickly that they are not experienced enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some solid commutative algebra. Definitely more than "some of the Commutative Algebra." Without that solid foundation, I think it is just not realistic to "go deep down into the subject." Perhaps not what you want to hear, but some topics are just not accessible with enough background.

I mean, keep in mind that Zariski and Samuel were planning to write a brief intro to the algebra you needed to do algebraic geometry; that ended up being a two-volume book.

The classic intro to commutative algebra at a level suitable to allow you to go into Algebraic Geometry is Atiyah and MacDonald's **Introduction to Commutative Algebra**, though some people find it too telegraphic. A much more expansive introduction, with examples that would be relevant, is Eisenbud's **Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry**.

Both of those presume a solid foundation of abstract algebra, especially rings and modules, as well as some field theory. Neither is for dilettantes.

A further issue is then what algebraic geometry you will want to pursue. The "classic theory" (what is in Hartshorne's first chapter) will not require much more beyond those, but if you venture into the modern theory (sheafs and schemes), you're also going to need some topology... You might be able to work with some small slice of algebraic geometry, say at the level of Fulton's **Algebraic Curves**, but it's going to be tough going.

When I went to graduate school, Algebraic Geometry was a "second year" subject; it was the rare student who could go straight into it from undergrad. That's one of the issues with Algebraic Geometry: there is a high entrance price.